# Angle after two rotations in $\mathbb R ^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

**Question**:  A rotation through $45^{\circ}$ about the *x*-axis is followed by a similar one about the z-axis. Show that the rotation corresponding to their combined effect has its axis inclined at equal angles $cos^{-1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{2}}}$ to the *x* and *z* axes.

**I tried** By Rodrigues' Rotation Theorem - or just by the standard rotation matrices - the first rotation, through $45^{\circ}$ about the *x*-axis, can be described by 
$R_1 = \left[ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
    0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
 \end{matrix} \right]$.

The second rotation, through $45^{\circ}$ about the *z*-axis, can be described by 
$R_2 = \left[ \begin{matrix}
    \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0  \\
    \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1  \\
 \end{matrix} \right]$.
So the combined rotation is $ R_2R_1 = = \left[ \begin{matrix}
    \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{-1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{2}  \\
    \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{1}{2}& \tfrac{-1}{2} \\
    0 & \tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{2}  \\
 \end{matrix} \right]$.
At last - by Rodigues' Rotation Theorem - $\cos\theta = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(Trace(R_2R_1) - 1\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2} - 1 \right)$ --- which isn't the right answer. What went wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first mistake is in the third row of $R_2 R_1$.  When you have that, a vector $\bf v$ in the direction of the axis is an eigenvector of $R_2 R_1$ for eigenvalue $1$.  The cosine of the angle between this and the unit vector $\bf u$ is ${\bf u} \cdot {\bf v}/\sqrt{{\bf v} \cdot {\bf v}}$.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking back at this and had one question --- $ \LARGE{1 -} $ What's the unit vector $\mathbf{u}$? Which vector are you referring to?

Comment: $\bf u$ is any unit vector.  For the given question you can look at $(1,0,0)$ and  $(0,0,1)$.